# How to deal with CS1721 when I really need to inherit from two classes?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In my C# code I want a `CustomIdentity` class that inherits from `System.MarshalByRefObject` and `System.Security.Principal.GenericIndentity` classes.

However when I try to write such inheritance C# would object with [CS1721 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c028c0t7.aspx) saying I can't directly inherit from more than one class.

Now in this case it's quite easy to overcome this - I'll inherit from `IIdentity`, add `GenericIdentity` member variable and reimplement all `IIdentity` methods via that member variable.

But how would I do in case I wanted to inherit from two classes with a huge set of methods?

Comment: The only way is encapsulation with interfaces, like you have said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. You can't.

That is not supported in C# or .NET.

You use multiple ***interface implementation***, and **at most** single (non-`object`) inheritance. In most cases, even single inheritance is vastly overused ;p

To absorb the methods, you'd have to use some kind of encapsulation. Extension methods *also* provide a way to share methods between types, for completeness.

Comment: Small Example please

Comment: @YumYumYum of which bit, specifically?

Comment: How "use multiple interface implementation" for  `public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, UIResponder {`

Answer (score 3):

Can't inherit from more than one class as you know... really the only way is to do as you say and use interfaces. Or change programming language to one that supports multiple inheritance, but I'm sure that won't help!