# Is there a convenient way to map all interface methods onto a subobject?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I need to [inherit from two classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6503093/57428). This is not allowed, so I can do the following: inherit from one of the classes and include the other class as a member variable, inherit from its interfaces and reimplement all methods of those interfaces by redirecting them onto that member variable:

```
interface SecondBaseInterface {
    void FirstMethod();
    void SecondMethod();
};

class MyClass : FirstBaseClass, SecondBaseInterface {

   public void FirstMethod()
   {
      secondBase.FirstMethod();
   }

   public void SecondMethod()
   {
      secondBase.SecondMethod();
   }

   SecondBaseClass secondBase = new SecondBaseClass();
};
```

now this works, but if there's a lot of methods in `SecondBaseInterface` it will require lot of typing of code that in fact does nothing useful and I'll have to maintain that code in case `SecondBaseInterface` changes.

Is there some C# feature that would tell the compiler "for all methods of `SecondBaseInterface` please call corresponding methods of this member variable" or some other convenient way to do such massive redirection?

Comment: As a side note, Resharper has a feature to generate such methods. Can save you from typing a lot, though won't save from messy code. **Generate->delegating members**

Comment: Regex, console, copy, paste? Oh wait you wanted convenient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple language feature that springs to mind, here are a few ideas:

1. Use .NET4.0 [DynamicObject](http://blog.colinmackay.net/archive/2009/06/04/Dynamic-Objects-in-C-4.0.aspx), where you can add properties / members on the fly.
2. Use Aspect Oriented Priogramming, or IL Weaving to add a mixin. See [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net) for example.
3. Use some form of code generation, e.g. [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to have that opportunity too, but I don't think it exists. Don't be afraid of doing this, though, if you really need a class that can act as both of its superclasses: it's the well-known [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) (as you probably know).

Answer (score 1):

I think almost every seasoned C# developer has probably wished for this at some stage - especially those who are former Delphi developers. It's called "implementation by delegation", and it was available in Delphi.

In fact the man responsible for this Delphi feature, Steve Teixeira, now works at MSFT. [Here's a blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/texblog/archive/2005/07/05/435854.aspx) where he talks about it.

Unfortunately C# can't do this as the the CLI doesn't support implementation by delegation.

Comment: You can do that in [Oxygene](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Implements_(keyword)) and in [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/Design_patterns#Proxy_design_pattern). Although, I think it has some [limitations](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/11/interface-implementation-through_09.html).

Answer (score 1):

I know the pain.

So much that I've started my own project to solve this: [NRoles](http://code.google.com/p/nroles/).

This brings a form of [trait (pdf)](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf) to C#.

Your code would look like this:

```
class FirstRole : Role {
  public void FirstMethod() { ... }
  public void SecondMethod() { ... }
}

class SecondRole : Role {
  ...
}

class MyClass : Does<FirstRole>, Does<SecondRole> {

}
```

You can also implement interfaces through the roles, and they'll be carried over to the composing class.